# Count number of characters in array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to count the number of total characters, excluding spaces, in (what I believe) is a pointer to an array of strings, called myArray.

I am struggling to work out what is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
char *myArray[1000] = {"Oh! ", "Hello ", "world."};

int count = 0, x;

for (x = 1; x <= 1000; ++x) {
    count += strlen(myArray[x]);
}

printf(count);
```

Desired output:

```
14
```

Comment: two questions -- do arrays start with 1 or 0? And what happens when x = 5 in your for statement?

Comment: Obviously, you can't use `strlen`. What have you tried? What problem are you having?

Comment: @ikegami - he is showing us exactly what he tried and all you have to do is read it to know the problem(s) he is having.

Comment: Arrays in C are `0` based. So please change the loop to `for (x = 0; x < 1000; ++x)`

Comment: @Hogan, this code -- one big issue. Everything is just wrong. Let's start from 1) are strings NULL-terminated or not? 2) `strlen()` needs an complementary call to `strspn()` (IIRC) to count whitespaces; 3) who on the Earth told that characters are one byte? 4) rest problems in the current comments / answers; 5) not found (yet) issues.

Comment: @0andriy - string constants are null terminated so I don't know what you mean by point one.  If he starts at zero and checks for null then I believe the only problem is counting the spaces.

Comment: Could you use pointer arithmetic, where you find the first and last memory locations of the initialized indices of the array, convert from hex to decimal, and subtract?

Comment: @AdrianM. No, because the string literal locations are not necessarily in any logical sequence, so you cannot get the total length by computing from the pointer values. And that would not deal with not-to-be-counted spaces anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code has a bunch of warnings. Unfortunately most C compilers do not issue warnings by default. Using `-Wall` turns on the most common warnings, though inexplicably not all of them.

That'll at least let you know that you're using `printf` incorrectly.

```
test.c:13:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type
      'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
    printf(count);
           ^~~~~
```

`printf` takes a format string which tells it the type of the thing its turning into a string.

```
printf("%d\n", count);
```

---

The next problem is this for loop.

```
for (x = 1; x <= 1000; ++x) {
```

That counts from 1 to 1000. But arrays in C start at 0. For a 1000 element array, you want to go from 0 to 999 else you'll miss the first element and then walk off the end of the array.

```
for (x = 0; x < 1000; ++x) {
```

---

While `myArray` has been allocated memory on the stack, and its first few elements have been set to constant strings, everything after that will be NULL (if it were allocated with `malloc` they would be filled with garbage). Since you're iterating over all the elements you're passing null pointers to `strlen` which is causing a segfault. You have to stop at the first null. Putting a null pointer at the end of an array of pointers is a good way to know when to stop.

Finally, since `myArray` is full of pointers to constant strings, you should declare it a list of pointers to `const char`. That will quiet this warning that's telling you you might be trying to modify constant strings.

```
test.c:5:28: warning: initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char [5]' discards
      qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    char *myArray[1000] = {"Oh! ", "Hello ", "world.", NULL};
```

Putting it all together...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char *myArray[1000] = {"Oh! ", "Hello ", "world."};

    int count = 0, x;

    for (x = 0; myArray[x] != NULL; ++x) {
        count += strlen(myArray[x]);
    }

    printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

---

Now that we've got the basic loop working, we can replace `strlen` with something that's going to count the characters while skipping whitespace.

[`ctype.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_character_classification) has a bunch of functions for finding out what *type* a *c*haracter is. We can use `isspace` to tell if a character is whitespace. But we're going to have to write our own function to loop through the string and examine all the characters.

There's a bunch of ways to loop through a string. We could get the length and iterate.

```
size_t len = strlen(string);
for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    ...
}
```

But C doesn't store the length of a string. `strlen` has to do its own loop through the string until it sees a null byte, so really the above is looping through the string twice. We can do better and iterate through looking for the null byte ourselves.

Again, we could use a normal for loop and loop until we see a null byte.

```
for( int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++ ) {
    ...
}
```

But we don't even need `i`. Instead, we can increment `string` directly, changing where the start of the string is, and always look at `string[0]`.

```
int count_chars_without_spaces( const char *string ) {
    int count = 0;

    for( ; string[0] != '\0'; string++ ) {
        if( !isspace(string[0]) ) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

That's ok because `string` is a variable local to that particular function. We can change it without changing the string.

So plug that in instead of `strlen` and you're good!

Comment: He doesn't want to count spaces in his answer.

Comment: @TonyTannous There, I fixed it. I was too busy fixing everything else to notice the original question.

Comment: @Hogan: explain me why `x < sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0])` is wrong? it works and other answers just do the same...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm not a fan of `x < sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0])` myself because it's of limited utility and new C coders will try to use it on heap memory and get confused. I'd rather techniques that work no matter how the array was allocated. But it isn't silly. You covered the issue of unnecessarily allocating 1000 places, that's good. As for the downvoting, I got downvoted and it helped me realize I'd missed something. And then I fixed mine. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre -- I've no idea where my comment went, I guess it was deleted by a moderator?  Strange.  I may have been harsh in my wording, I wanted to express something similar to Schwern so I will try an be clearer.  I believe Occam's Razor applies here -- complex pointer arithmetic is less clear and harder to maintain than other options available.   When I said "silly" I meant more obtuse and complex than it needed to be.

Comment: yeah my comments were deleted too. Don't worry, I didn't flag your comment!

Comment: I try use "strlen" and "sizeof" from my char *variable[] and I get from my strlen 3 positions of 5 and size of get 20 from 5.... What I'm wrong ?

Comment: @delive Sorry, there's not enough detail for me to answer. If you post it as a question referencing this answer maybe you'll get help.

Comment: is a little code For example :  *ingredients[5] = {"raw", "salt", "rennet", "e", "milk enzymes"}; I get  3 with strlen(ingredients)

Comment: @delive `strlen(ingredients)` is nonsense, you're asking for the string length of an array of strings, and should have given you a bunch of compiler warnings. Again, there isn't enough detail here. Ask this as its own question.

Answer (score 6):

Yuu can use standard functions from `ctype.h` to identify the character class. For example, using `issspace()` you can find if a character is a whitespace and if so, you can ignore it.

You are looping over indexes from 1 to 1000. Indexing in C starts from 0 and goes upto N-1. Besides, your contains only 3 pointers; rest are just NULL (implicitly zero initialized).

Another problem is you are printing `count` without a format specifier. `count` being `int`, you would need to use `%d` as format specifier. However, you can use `size_t` as that's the type string functions return and the type that can hold the largest object.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{

char *myArray[] = {"Oh! ", "Hello ", "world."};

size_t count = 0, x, y;

for (x = 0; x < sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0]); x++) {
    for (y = 0; myArray[x][y]; y++) {
        count += (isspace((unsigned char)myArray[x][y]) == 0);
    }
}

printf("Total chars: %zu\n", count);
}
```

Comment: "*[size_t is] the type that can hold the largest object*" That would be big enough for the length of one string, but it's storing the total size of many strings; `size_t` isn't necessarily big enough. Still preferable to `int`.

Comment: @Schwern `size_t` may not be to hold size of many strings. But I don't see how that's a justification to use `int`. At least, `size_t` avoids integer overflow and probably can hold larger values than `int`.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's better than `int` and is probably so enormous that code could never reach it. But `size_t` can still overflow. `size_t size = SIZE_MAX; printf("%zu\n", size+1);` is 0. It's not a practical problem, more about the perils using a type to add together numbers of the same type.

Comment: @Schwern That's not true. `size_t` can never overflow (just like all other unsigned integers). When `size_t` wraps around, it's at least incorrect result; whereas, when an `int` overflows, it's *undefined behaviour* which is certainly worse.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with this question, most of which are addressed by Schwern's answer. I'll address some more things though, including the point in the original question about not counting spaces:

1. To reiterate, C arrays are 0-indexed.
2. You probably want an unbounded loop, so that you can add more elements to your array without changing the code (and the number `1000` convolutes the solution). At this point, the maximum value of `x` becomes `sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0])`, the number of elements. You would also let the compiler decide what size to make the array by dropping the `1000` from `myArray`'s definition: `char *myArray[] = {"Oh! ", "Hello ", "world."};`
3. The top level loop counts the string length of the full string, but you only want non-space characters. There are many ways to do this, but the most straightforward way is to just count the non-space characters in a nested loop.

Given these things, the following code obtains the desired output:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
  char *myArray[] = {"Oh! ", "Hello ", "world."};
  int count = 0;
  int arrayLength = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]);

  for (int x = 0; x < arrayLength; x++) {
    int stringLength = strlen(myArray[x]);

    for (int y = 0; y < stringLength; y++) {
      char currentCharacter = myArray[x][y];

      if (currentCharacter != ' ') {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

Compile it:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

then run it:

```
./test
```

and it should output:

```
14
```

Given the `arrayLength` calculation, we can now add a word to `myArray` and see that the output changes with expectation:

```
char *myArray[] = {"Oh! ", "Hello ", "world.", "  test     "};
```

Because there are only 4 non-space characters (`test`), this should output:

```
18
```

Answer (score 0):

A barebones version, for a mildly low-level illustration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

char * stringArray[200] = {"O  n e ", " Two  ", "Thre e  ", "Four    ", " F i ve    !"};
int i, j, chars; 
i = j = chars = 0;

while(stringArray[i] != '\0'){
    char temp = stringArray[i][j];
    switch(temp){
        case ' ':
            j++;
            break;
        case '\0':
            i++; 
            j=0;
            break;
        default:
            j++;
            chars++;
            break;           
    }    
}

printf("%d\n", chars);
//o/p == 20

return 0;

}
```